# Entity framework - code first data access

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm looking for your opinions about ways to improve the access to data in my application. I develop web applications, using Entity Framework 6 code first, and Autofac for dependency injection.

Before you dive in the code, keep in mind that all components in my application (except for the problematic `RepositoriesFactory` you will see below) are registered by the IoC container. My root (Startapp) registers all components, using a .dll I developed that supplies API for DI (Autofac wrapper), that's because I don't want Autofac references in my web project. Furthermore, I want this .dll I developed to be known and used only in my root because I know this is the best practice.

My data management:

```
public abstract class BaseEntityObject
{
    [Key]
    public int DbIndex {get; set;}
}

public class Letter : BaseEntityObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public string Title {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public string Content {get; set;}

    public virtual Folder Folder {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public int FolderId {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime CreationDate {get; set;}
}

public class Folder : BaseEntityObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public List<Letter> Letters {get; set;} 
}

public IRepository<T> where T: BaseEntityObject
{
    void Add(T entity);

    void Remove(T entity);

    List<T> Get();

    T FindById(int id);

    int SaveChanges();

    void Dispose();

}


public abstract class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;

    public EFRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public abstract List<T> Get();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Add(item);
    }

    public void Remove(T item)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Remove(item);
    }

    public void Update(T item)
    {
        Context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Context.Dispose();
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public T FindById(int id)
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().Find(id); 
    }
}


public LettersRepository : EFRepository<Letter>
{
    public LettersRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) {}

    // Override for case includes will be needed in future
    public override List<T> Get()
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().ToList();
    }
}

public FoldersRepository : EFRepository<Folder>
{
    public FoldersRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) {}

    public override List<T> Get()
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().Include("Letters").ToList();
    }
}


public class DataService
{
   private IRepositoriesFactory _factory

   public DataService(IRepositoriesFactory repoFactory)
   {
       _factory = repoFactory;
   }

   public void AddFolder(Folder folder)
   {
       using (var foldersRepository = _factory.Create<FoldersRepository>())
       {
           try
           {
                foldersRepository.Add(folder)
                foldersRepository.SaveChanges();
           }
           catch(Exception)
            {
                Log ("AddFolder failed");
            }
       }
   }

   public void AddLetter(Letter letter)
   {
       using (var lettersRepository = _factory.Create<LettersRepository>())
       {
           try
           {
                foldersRepository.Add(letter)
                foldersRepository.SaveChanges();
           }
           catch(Exception)
            {
                Log ("AddLetter failed");
            }
       }
   }

   public void RemoveFolder(int id)
   {
       using (var foldersRepository = _factory.Create<FoldersRepository>())
       {
           try
           {
                var folder = foldersRepository.FindById(id);
                foldersRepository.Remove(folder)
                foldersRepository.SaveChanges();
           }
           catch(Exception)
            {
                Log ("RemoveFolder failed");
            }
       }
   }

   public void RemoveLetter(int id)
   {
       using (var lettersRepository = _factory.Create<LettersRepository>())
       {
           try
           {
                var letter = lettersRepository.FindById(id);
                lettersRepository.Remove(letter);
                lettersRepository.SaveChanges();
           }
           catch(Exception)
            {
                Log ("RemoveLetter failed");
            }
       }
   }

   public bool ChangeLetterFolder(int letterId, int destinationFolder)
   {
        using (var lettersRepository = _factory.Create<LettersRepository>())
        {
            try
            {
                var letter = lettersRepository.FindById(letterId);
                letter.FolderId = destinationFolder;
                lettersRepository.Update(letter);
                lettersRepository.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                Log (string.Format("Changing letter {0} folder failed", letterId));
            }
        }
   }

   public List<Letter> GetLettersAfterSpecificDate(DateTime date)
   {
       using (var lettersRepository = _factory.Create<LettersRepository>())
        {
            try
            {
                return lettersRepository.Get().Where(x => x.CreationDate < date).ToList();
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                Log (string.Format("Getting all letters before : {0} failed", date));
            }
        }
   }   
}

public interface IApplicationDbContext
{
    DbSet<Folder> Folders {get; set;}   
    DbSet<Letter> Letters {get; set;}
}

public ApplicationDbContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Folder> Folders {get; set;}

    public DbSet<Letter> Letters {get; set;}

    public ApplicationDbContext () : base("name=Application.DbConntection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>());
    }
}

public interface IRepositoriesFactory
{
    IRepository<BaseEntityObject> Create<T>();
}

// I truely hate this piece of code,
// but don't know how to use dependceny injection without having a mess with 
// my references in order to register this factory
public class RepositoriesFactory : IRepositoriesFactory
{
    public IRepository<BaseEntityObject> Create<T>()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(FoldersRepository))
            return new FoldersRepository(new ApplicationDbContext());
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(LettersRepository))
            return new LettersRepository(new ApplicationDbContext());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The factory object is pretty easy. You just need a little class reflection:

```
public class RepositoryFactory
{
    public RepositoryFactory()
    {
        context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    private ApplicationDbContext context;

    public object Create<T>()
    {
        Type repositoryType = typeof(T);
        ConstructorInfo constructor = repositoryType.GetConstructor(new Type[1] { typeof(ApplicationDbContext) });

        if (constructor == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No Constructor found for " + repositoryType.FullName);

        return constructor.Invoke(new object[1] { context });
    }
}
```

I would also recommend added a `where` constraint to your type argument:

```
public object Create<T>() where T : IRepository<BaseEntityObject>
{
    // ...
}
```

Also notice that the `ApplicationDbContext` object is now a private field, which allows your repositories to share the same data context. This also keeps you from editing this class each time you create a new repository.

---

Now on to more pressing issues. I see lots of `try-catch-swallow` code -- code that catches exceptions and swallows them.

*Please, for the sake of Future S. Peter do not do this!!*

If an exception gets thrown in the data layer, let it bubble up. Don't swallow it -- even if you log it! Let the application blow sky high. If you add a record or folder and that operation fails, that is a catastrophic problem the deserves the immediate cessation of program logic.

See my related answer (along with some humor and sarcasm):

[Returning status codes from business layer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63049/returning-status-codes-from-business-layer/63052#63052)

Comment: Accepted everything you said but didn't understand how the same context will be used.. Only one context ia created inside the factory ctor? When does it get disposed of?

Comment: @S.Peter: That brings up a good question I have about your code as well. When does the DB context get disposed? Can you post some example code of how you use the repository factory and repositories?

Comment: In a finally block after each try catch in my data service, forgot to mention it.
Erlier I seperated the context management and it looked like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259320/ef-best-way-to-manage-dbcontext/35281068?noredirect=1#comment58300091_35281068

Answer (score 1):

You should use `virtual` keyword if you want to lazy load data.

```
[DataMember]
public virtual ICollection<Letter> Letters {get; set;}
```

For `IRepository<T>`, I would suggest changing `List<T> Get();` to `IList<T> Get()` or `IEnumeratble<T>` depends on your needs.

In the abstract class `EFRepository`, you could create a variable `_dbSet`so that you don't have to repeat `Context.Set<T>()`

```
public abstract class EFRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext _context;
    protected readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public EFRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet=context.Set<T>();
    }
    ........
    .........
```

In my opinion, your abstract class EFRepository doesn't need to implement the interface. I would recommend you create `ILettersRepository` and `IFoldersRepository` instead and having both of them to inherit `IRepository`. This would give you the option to create methods that are only needed for a particular repository. For example:

```
public interface IFolderRepository : IRepository<Folder>{
   Folder GetFolderByName(string name);
}

public FoldersRepository : EFRepository<Folder>, IFolderRepository
{
    public FoldersRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) {}

    public override List<T> Get()
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().Include("Letters").ToList();
    }

    public Folder GetFolderByName(string name){
     //TODO
    }
}
```

In such way you don't even need a factory, you can directly inject your `ILettersRepository` and `IFoldersRepository` into your service code:

```
public class DataService
{
   private readonly IFoldersRepository _foldersRepository;
   private readonly ILettersRepository _lettersRepository;

   public DataService(IFoldersRepository foldersRepository, ILettersRepository lettersRepository)
   {
       _foldersRepository = foldersRepository;
       _lettersRepository=lettersRepository;
   }
   ..........
   .........
}
```